# Dataclasses and slots causing ValueError: 'b' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable

Tags: python, python-3.9, python-dataclasses, slots

I don't understand the error message and also couldn't find other SO questions and answers helping me to understand this. The MWE is tested with Python 3.9.2. I'm aware that there is a `slots=True` parameter in Pythons 3.10 dataclasses. But this isn't an option here.

The error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/dc.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Foo:
ValueError: 'b' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

Why does that happen? I even don't understand the background of that error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env pyhton3
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(init=False)
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')
    a: int
    b: list[str] = field(init=False)

    def __init__(self, a, ccc):
        self.a = a

        # b = _some_fancy_modifications(ccc)

        self.b = b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo(1, list('bar'))
```

The member `b` is not given as an argument of `__init__()` but computed based on the argument `ccc`. Because of that I think I need to write my own `__init__()` (`@dataclass(init=False)`) and the `b` member shouldn't be initialized by dataclass (`field(init=False)`). Maybe I misunderstood something here?

Comment: It happens because `'b' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable`, the class variable being `b: list[str] = field(init=False)`. Which one of those should `Foo.b` be?

Comment: Why isn't there a conflict with `a`?

Comment: ...because you don't _have_ a class variable named `a`. You don't assign a value, so it's just in `__annotations__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `__slots__` to work, Python has to insert special [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) objects into the class dict to manage attribute access. Otherwise, since the attributes aren't stored in the instance dict, attribute lookup would be completely unable to find your attributes. Descriptors tell the attribute lookup machinery how to find special attributes.

For the `b` slot to work, Python has to insert a descriptor for that attribute corresponding to the `'b'` key in your class dict. But you've already put something there: the `field` object you created. You can't have a `field` object *and* a slot descriptor as values for the same key. Python recognizes that this is a problem, and raises an error to tell you that you need to do something about this.

This isn't really something you can fix on your end. `__slots__` support for dataclasses needs changes to the dataclass machinery, changes that happened in 3.10. In 3.9, you're stuck not using slots with dataclasses.

Comment: I wonder: Does it even make sense to use `init=False` on classlevel **and** attribute level?

Comment: @buhtz: Maybe in some weird cases with dataclass inheritance, but any cases I can think of involve horribly confusing code that shouldn't be written that way in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

This is not related to dataclasses. A slot is realized as a class variable of an internal type "member_descriptor".

Try:

```
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')

print(repr(Foo.a))
print(repr(Foo.a.__class__))
```

Output:

```
<member 'a' of 'Foo' objects>
<class 'member_descriptor'>
```

Comment: And? How does this answer the question?

Comment: @buhtz It answers the first question (but could be more elaborate, ok).